# what crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml generate msp and orderer.blcok about Fabric sample chaincode-docker-devmode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I know cryptogen could generate msp ,and  configtxgen tools could generate genesis.block and myc.tx, I want to know what crypto-config.yaml and configtx.yaml could generate them, and where to explain notion about them detail??

Answer (score 2):

**cryptogen** is just a convenience tool to make it easier to get up and running with a sample network quickly without having to go through the process of setting up certificate authorities and gathering the cryptographic material required for X509-based MSPs. Not sure exactly what answer you are looking for, but it basically generates MSPs per the specification outlined [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html).  The format for crypto-config.yaml itself is described in the yaml file itself.  You can generate a template file without generating the actual crypto material using `cryptogen showtemplate`.  The generated yaml should provide the details / options which are available.  It is also possible to generate MSPs using the fabric-ca and [fabric-ca-client](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#enrolling-a-peer-identity) as well.

For **configtxgen** and **configtx.yaml**, have you looked at http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configtx.html and http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configtxgen.html ?

Comment: What you point out I have read, just want to know the detail notion, Actually the authority do know introduce them detail.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are looking for here?  Could you provide a few examples of the details you are looking for?